# Is CyclicBarrier thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to use a CyclicBarrier object as a static member, I have multi threads running which will be modifying the CyclicBarrier object state, is it safe to do so ?

Comment: Why do you have doubts?

Comment: I couldn't find something online that assures it's thread safe, what if two threads trying to change the state at the same time, can it then wait forever ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html

Comment: `java.util.concurrent` isn't enough proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javadoc says:

> Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to calling await() happen-before actions that are part of the barrier action, which in turn happen-before actions following a successful return from the corresponding await() in other threads.

And a few other things.

So yes ... it is thread-safe<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - The javadoc doesn't use the words "thread-safe".  However, I think that is because thread safety is a rubbery concept.  The definitions I have seen say effectively say that something is "thread safe" if it is correct (works according to specification) if there are multiple threads.  If you simply say X is "thread-safe", it begs the question: what is the specified behaviour?  What does "correct" mean? The javadoc sidesteps this by simply stating the key synchronization properties ... in a very precise terms defined by the JLS.</sup>

<sup>Why do I bring this up?  To point out that simply asking *"is X thread-safe?"* is superficial, and liable to lead you into problems ... if that is the full extent of your analysis.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

The whole point of `CyclicBarrier` is to synchronize multiple threads.  The only methods that change its state are `await` (with and without timeout) and `reset`, and the documentation for those methods clearly describes how they interact with other threads.

Yes, it's thread-safe.